# Cacheable HTTPS Response CVSS

Tags: caching, cvss

https://portswigger.net/kb/issues/00700100_cacheable-https-response

> Applications should return caching directives instructing browsers not to store local copies of any sensitive data

Which CVSS vector I should assign to a web application which use `Cache-Control: private` for anything (also `sessionID` and pages with personal sensitive information)?

Comment: Assuming that you mean with `sessionID` the cookie used to maintain the session. This is not covered by the caching policy and keeping  the sessionID between requests is even essential for the application to work.

Comment: I quoted some statements
https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/06-Session_Management_Testing/04-Testing_for_Exposed_Session_Variables.html 

"Furthermore, whenever the Session ID is passed, directives should be in place to prevent its caching by intermediate and even local caches"

furthermore "The Expires: 0 and Cache-Control: max-age=0 directives should be used to further ensure caches do not expose the data. Each request/response passing Session ID data should be examined to ensure appropriate cache directives are in use."

Comment: I see - in this context it is about sessionID as hidden field etc in the page.

Comment: So you mean that recommendations are valid only when the sessionid is passed through hidden fields and not when is passed through http headers/cookies?

Comment: As I said, the sessionID needs to be preserved between requests to maintain the session. This is true  no matter if implemented as cookie (most common way), as URL parameter or inside the page. The associated risks can be mitigated by having a limited life time for the session id though, so that the information are useless instead of sensitive after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be fitting:
`CVSS:3.0/AV:P/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:H/I:N/A:N`

> If sensitive information in application responses is stored in the local cache, then this may be retrieved by other users who have **access to the same computer** at a future time.

Unless you have another exploit to access the computer, you'll need physical access. It's fairly easy to do and doesn't require PR or UI.
Let me know what you think.